# NameError: name 'self' is not defined - but I think I did it correctly

Tags: python

I just started learning Python from scratch and now I am trying to learn classes concept and can't seem to find why my code is returning an error.

Could you please teach me what I did incorrectly?

```
class User():
    """A simple database with restaurant information."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, gender, age):
        """Initialize user's name, gender and age info."""
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age
        self.login_attempts = 0
    
    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        """Increments the value of login_attempts by 1"""
        self.login_attempts += 1
    
    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        """Resets the value of login_attempts."""
        self.login_attempts = 0
    
user3 = User('mino', 'lee', 'male', 35)

print("\n")
user3.increment_login_attempts()
user3.increment_login_attempts()
print("\nLogin attempted " + str(self.login_attempts) + " times.")

user3.reset_login_attempts()
print("\nLogin attempted " + str(self.login_attempts) + " times.")
```

Comment: Try replacing `self` with `user3` in the `print`s.

Comment: Where the code says `print("\nLogin attempted " + str(self.login_attempts) + " times.")`, what do you expect `self` to refer to? Why? (Hint: is this code inside the class definition?) Which instance do you want to check the `.login_attempts` of? What name is locally used for that instance?

Comment: Sidenote: `print` converts its arguments to `str` automatically and joins them on spaces, so you could simplify: `print("Login attempted", user3.login_attempts, "times.")`

Comment: What if you had `user1 = User(...)` and `user2 = User(...)`: which user do you think `self` would refer to in this case? There's nothing terribly special about the name `self`; it's just the conventional name for the first parameter of an instance method, and like any parameter, it's just a local variable in the scope of the method.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Although I can't understand everything you kindly pointed out, I think I got the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"self" only applies if you're in a class method which has a "self" parameter.  From the outside, you need to use the object name:

```
print("\n")
user3.increment_login_attempts()
user3.increment_login_attempts()
print("\nLogin attempted " + str(user3.login_attempts) + " times.")

user3.reset_login_attempts()
print("\nLogin attempted " + str(user3.login_attempts) + " times.")
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim! I spent almost an hour struggling with this and your explanation was really helpful to realise what I missed.

Comment: Thank you. Still totally new and inexperienced to this whole space... Just did as advised. :)